# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value "XXX" to data type int

Tags: sql-server-2008, int, type-conversion, nvarchar

I would like to convert the below query from nvarchar to int

```
SELECT 'A' + RIGHT('000' + CAST((MAX(UserID) + 1) as nvarchar(50)), 3) FROM users
```

How do I do that?

This is my table:

[image]

And this is my data:

```
ID  | UserID  | Name

1      A001    XYZ
```

Comment: if you add 'A' or any alphabetic character than you can't convert into int. tell me why you want to convert it in nvarchar to int

Comment: actually I need to get the last userid from the table and increment its value by '1' or if there is any other simpler way please tell me how do I get that value

Comment: provide me table script and sample data.

Comment: @RiteshKhatri-Added please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now try this one.

```
    Select 'A' + RIGHT('000' + 
    CAST((MAX(Convert(Int,SUBSTRING(USERID,2,LEN(USERID))))+ 1) as nvarchar(50)), 3)
    From users
```